# How could I build a resizizing or collapsing Textbox in D3.JS for mitch-tree

Tags: svg, d3.js, tree, textbox, resize

Hallo I am currently trying to build a tree in D3.js.
For this I donwloadet the repository of the mitch-tree:

https://github.com/deltoss/d3-mitch-tree

I wantet to ask, if maybe somebody already has expirience with this issue?
So, I build a tree with processcharts.
But I have the problem, that the text hast to fit the boxes right nor, or it will get cut out.

It would be great to be able to fit the boxes to the content, so making them resizeable or, maybe make the boxes collapsable..

Maybe somebody hast a tipp for me, how to reach that goal.

[image]

I think I found the part of the code where the cutting/ resizing might be happaning for my textBox.

But I am really not sure..

If I got it right, the textbox resizes already what is inside with this function and cuts the words, that are to much for my box are out:

```
   // D3Plus Textbox with resizing capability
        var d3PlusBodyTextBox = new d3PlusTextBox()
            .select(element) // Sets the D3Plus code to append to the specified DOM element.
            .data(singledOutData)
            .text((data, index, arr) => {
                return self.getBodyDisplayText.call(self, data);
            })
            .textAnchor("middle")
            .verticalAlign("middle")
            .fontSize(13) // in pixels
            .x(nodeBodyBoxPadding.left)
            .y(recalculatedPaddingTop - nodeBodyBoxHeight / 2)
            .width(nodeBodyBoxWidth - nodeBodyBoxPadding.left - nodeBodyBoxPadding.right)
            .height(nodeBodyBoxHeight - recalculatedPaddingTop - nodeBodyBoxPadding.bottom)
            .ellipsis((text, line) => {
                // If text was cut-off, add tooltip
                selection.append("title")
                    .text(self.getBodyDisplayText(data));
                return ((text.replace(/\.|,$/g, "")) + "...");
            })
            .render();
    });
```

Has anyone maybe a tipp for me how to change it in a good and functional way?

Thanks in advance :)